# Print all data of a table

Tags: php, css, mysql, sql, html-table

I have a "Clients" table and an other called "Contacts". I have done a master/detail page, in the master page, there is the name of the client and in the detail one there is the phone, email, fax, etc. of the client. Moreover, for each client I have some contacts and that's why I have created a spry menu in the detail page that show a maximum of 4 contacts for each client. With the following sentence, the contact is printed only if he/she belongs to the client:

```
<?php if($row_DetailRS1['Nombre']==$row_Recordset1['Nombre de la empresa'])
{ echo $row_Recordset1['Nombre del contacto']; }?>
```

But the problem is that the 4 bars that the menu have, are inputed with the same      contact. I give you an example:

Clients table: (Seat, 938314587, seat@gmail.com, etc); (Audi, 93564215,     audi@didi.com, etc); (BMW, 93145698, bmw@m3.com, etc) 
Contacts table: (Nerea, Audi, 93654565, etc); (Alberto, Audi, 93654789, etc)  (Marta, Seat 93145697, etc); (Oscar, Audi, 93656987, etc)

Masetr page:
Audi

Detail page:
Audi
93564215
audi@didi.com

SPRAY MENU   Nerea   Info of Nerea
             Alberto   Info of Alberto
             Oscar   Info of Oscar

It should be like it is above, but it becomes like that:

SPRAY MENU   Nerea   Info of Nerea
             Nerea   Info of Nerea
             Nerea   Info of Nerea

ACTUALIZATION:

I have improved a bit the code but it still doesn't work... Now it only shows me the first row of the table "Contacts", and if the first row have another client, it prints a white blanket instead of jumping to find if that sentence is true for the next row:

```
<?php if($row_DetailRS1['Nombre']==$row_Recordset1['Nombre de la empresa'])
{ echo $row_Recordset1['Nombre del contacto']; }?>
```

I put the code there:

```
mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_DetailRS1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE Nombre = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_DetailRS1, "text"));
$query_limit_DetailRS1 = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_DetailRS1, $startRow_DetailRS1, $maxRows_DetailRS1);
$DetailRS1 = mysql_query($query_limit_DetailRS1, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_DetailRS1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($DetailRS1);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_DetailRS1'])) {
$totalRows_DetailRS1 = $_GET['totalRows_DetailRS1'];
} else {
$all_DetailRS1 = mysql_query($query_DetailRS1);
$totalRows_DetailRS1 = mysql_num_rows($all_DetailRS1);
}
$totalPages_DetailRS1 = ceil($totalRows_DetailRS1/$maxRows_DetailRS1)-1;

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM contactos";
$result = mysql_query($query_Recordset1);
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());

<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#0000CC" class="tgnr">Nombre</th>
<td bgcolor="#0066FF" class="datos"><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['Nombre']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#0000CC" class="tgnr">Direccion</th>
<td bgcolor="#0066FF" class="datos"><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['Direccion']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#0000CC" class="tgnr">Ciudad</th>
<td bgcolor="#0066FF" class="datos"><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['Ciudad']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#0000CC" class="tgnr">CP</th>
<td bgcolor="#0066FF" class="datos"><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['CP']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#0000CC" class="tgnr">Pais</th>
<td bgcolor="#0066FF" class="datos"><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['Pais']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#0000CC" class="tgnr">Telefono 1</th>
<td bgcolor="#0066FF" class="datos"><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['Telefono 1']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#0000CC" class="tgnr">Telefono 2</th>
<td bgcolor="#0066FF" class="datos"><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['Telefono 2']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#0000CC" class="tgnr">Pagina web</th>
<td bgcolor="#0066FF" class="datos"><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['Pagina web']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#0000CC" class="tgnr">Fax</th>
<td bgcolor="#0066FF" class="datos"><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['Fax']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#0000CC" class="tgnr">Correo 1</th>
<td bgcolor="#0066FF" class="datos"><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['Correo 1']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th bgcolor="#0000CC" class="tgnr">Correo 2</th>
<td bgcolor="#0066FF" class="datos"><?php echo $row_DetailRS1['Correo 2']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php $NFilas = mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarVertical">
<li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#"><?php for ( $i = 1; $i < $NFilas; $i++) {
if($row_DetailRS1['Nombre']==$row_Recordset1['Nombre de la empresa']){ echo      $row_Recordset1['Nombre del contacto']; }}?></a>
<ul>
 <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Departamento</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Departamento'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Teléfono</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Telefono'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Fax</a>
  <ul>
</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Fax'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Email</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Email'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#"><?php for ( $i = $i; $i < $NFilas; $i++)      {if($row_DetailRS1['Nombre']==$row_Recordset1['Nombre de la empresa']){ echo     $row_Recordset1['Nombre del contacto']; }} ?></a>
<ul>
<li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Departamento</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Departamento'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Teléfono</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Telefono'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Fax</a>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Fax'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Email</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Email'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#"><?php for ( $i = $i; $i < $NFilas; $i++)    {if($row_DetailRS1['Nombre']==$row_Recordset1['Nombre de la empresa']){ echo    $row_Recordset1['Nombre del contacto']; }} ?></a>
<ul>
<li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Departamento</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Departamento'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Teléfono</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Telefono'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Fax</a>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Fax'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Email</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Email'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#"><?php for ( $i = $i; $i < $NFilas; $i++)     {if($row_DetailRS1['Nombre']==$row_Recordset1['Nombre de la empresa']){ echo    $row_Recordset1['Nombre del contacto']; }}?></a>
<ul>
<li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Departamento</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Departamento'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Teléfono</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Telefono'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Fax</a>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Fax'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Email</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Email'] ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: "But the problem is that the 4 bars that the menu have, are inputed with the same contact."
"I have improved a bit the code but it still doesn't work..."
The question would be: do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @user3894819: Welcome to StackOverflow. While we are eager to help you, your question is a bit too long. Please try to pinpoint your problem, remove unnecessary code that does not contribute to the problem, and make the question smaller.

Comment: Please tidy up your code indentation, it's hardly readable.